Changing a passenger with extra baggage with Wizz
I think the answer is no, but still I wonder if anyone might know. Basically, I've got 3 tickets with Wizz. One of the tickets includes extra baggage and the other two only free options. We usually do it as it's enough for us. But the passenger who's got the ticket with extra baggage cannot travel. I can cancel the ticket but the refund is only 10 quid and the extra baggage option cost me 48 quid. I wonder if it's possible to transfer the extra baggage option to a different passenger in the group? I looked at the name change option but it costs around 55 quid.

I don't know the answer to your question. But Wizz is a low-cost carrier, and low-cost carriers' business plans are usually low fare cost with few or no extras, and high fees for other extras or changes. Seems very unlikely that'd Wizz would be cooperative in a ticket change that would save you money at Wizz' expense.
